# Spring app not properly accessible on third party tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a Spring app on localhost running on:

Tomcat version: 6.0
JDK version: 1.6

I just moved it to a shared third party server running on:

Tomcat version 5.5
JDK version 1.6

Because of this, I think there's some incompatibility issues because of which I'm not able to access the app properly on shared third party server. I'm able to access only the homepage http://www.nepaladz.com , but the other links throw a 404.

1. Since homepage is running well, does it mean there's no incompatibility issue?
2. On my localhost, I tried to run it on Tomcat version 5.5, but I get this error while trying to add project to server

> Tomcat version 5.5 only supports J2EE 1.2, 1.3, and 1.4 Web modules

How can I possibly solve this issue?

Thanks for help.
James

Comment: Do you have any errors from the log?

Comment: No. I'm on shared server, and have no access to logs :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the major difference between Tomcat 5.5 and Tomcat 6 is, that Tomcat 5.5 supports only jsp version 2.0. (Tomcat 6 supports jsp version 2.1).

So check that you use only Jsp version 2.0

**EDIT**

```
Servlet/JSP Spec    Apache Tomcat version   Actual release revision Minimum Java Version
3.0/2.2             7.0.x                   7.0.22                  1.6
2.5/2.1             6.0.x                   6.0.33                  1.5
2.4/2.0             5.5.x                   5.5.34                  1.4
2.3/1.2             4.1.x (archived)        4.1.40 (archived)       1.3
2.2/1.1             3.3.x (archived)        3.3.2 (archived)        1.1
```

Source: http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: Ok, so it supports 2.0 and 2.4, and I have set it up for 2.4 in web.xml with **<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">**. But it still says **Tomcat version 5.5 only supports J2EE 1.2, 1.3, and 1.4 Web modules** when I try adding my project to Tomcat 5.5 server

Comment: Question from above: **Since homepage is running well, does it mean there's no incompatibility issue?**

Comment: I do not know what your hompage is and how is it related to the tomcat and the application that does not run well.

Comment: @James: I have rolled back the you last edit of my answer, because it is NOT your personal notepad.

Comment: I created a new Dynamic Web Project with module version 2.4, copied my src and WebContent to this new project and I was able to run my app on Tomcat 5.5. The new web.xml has **<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">**

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have access to the log file for the Tomcat 5.5. Then install a Tomcat 5.5 on your computer.

I guess the error in the logfile will tell you where the problem is.